# I need to be able to load files into a string a compile time with C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I need a portable cross-platform way to load text files at compile time. My application is a virtual machine for a domain specific language that I have written so I need the core class files to be embedded. They should not be loaded at runtime. Is this possible with C/C++ without the need of a third party library or tool.

Assume some `main.cpp` file as follows.

```
// load some core script
static constexpr std::string coreScript = LOAD_FILE("/path/to/lib/com/example/Person.mylang");

// main()
int main()
{
    // some setup function that returns an instance of the FFI
    MyLangEnv *env = mlvm_setup(); // some setup function that returns an instance of the FFI

    // register native Person type
    env->native()->type("com/example/Person", &Person::construct)
    ->property("firstName", &Person::firstName)
    ->property("lastName", &Person::lastName)
    ->property("age", &Person::age)
    ->method("speak", &Person::speak);
    ;

    // run script so that the class is exposed to runtime
    env->run()->mylangScript(coreScript);

    // now person can be instantiated
    Person *person = env->make()->object("com/example/Person", "Jane", "Doe", 22);
    assert(person);

    // set global
    env->set()->global("person", person);

    // eval
    env->eval("print(person.firstName)"); // outputs "Jane"

    // call speak()
    env->call()->property(person, "speak");


    // run gc() and destroy environment
    env->kill();
    return 0;
}
```

I would like the script to work in this way. Is this possible in C++ in a way that also will work with Objective-C++?

Comment: You can store the content of the file in a static variable. That way it will be embedded in the binary.

Comment: I've had a few similar cases where I've wanted resources compiled into the program. Just make a little program or script that takes your raw resources and wraps them in `C++` code. Add the program/script as a compiler in your makefile. If a resource is changed, the program/script  kicks in and regenerates new output that can be used when building the rest.

Comment: Please describe what you imagine will happen or will become possible if you "load text files at compile time".

Comment: @Yunnosch I need to distribute my library across multiple projects and when a program is compiled my library should automatically include the needed source files since they cannot be guaranteed to exist at runtime unless they are within the binary of the application. I just need the text file to be in a string within a variable so that the data can be used at runtime. I don't want to have to load the files externally at runtime because this would make the library (which depends on these files) less portable.

Comment: @Jasoule That's what I tried to describe above. I've compiled text files and sound files etc. into programs using the described approach. If you have many files, put them in a `tgz` or `zip` and include the whole thing in the program.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you Ted for your response. Do you have any resources that could show me step by step how to achieve that? That would be a practical solution.

Comment: Well, lets say that you have a text file that you want to embed into your program. It's just a matter of reading the text file and produce one `.cpp` file with something like `const char[] textfile = "<fill with the data you read from the actual text file>";` and then to create a `.h` file that extern declares that variable. Simplified of course, but I don't think there's a ready tool for it (unless you count the resource compilers that comes with misc. IDE:s).

Comment: The tool for producing the `.cpp` and `.h` file would be one that you make yourself. It can be a simple script or a compiled program. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advise of @TedLyngmo to solve this problem.

I ended up writing a Python script that traversed a directory to load all of the source files of my language and generated a large C++ file containing all of the data needed to use within the virtual machine at runtime. I found resources online to help me with the API and I had some familiarity with Python. I used the `os` module to get all files in a directory and the string method `endswith` to test if a file had the correct extension. Finally I generated the new file via open('path/to/generated.cpp', 'w+') if the file did not exist and open('path/to/generated.cpp', 'w') if it did exist.

I have not figured out how to get Xcode to run python script at build time but I did get it to run a bash. I'll have to make adjustments later. For now this works fine.